# How to move one image intersect by other image on view using UITouch

Tags: objective-c, animation, uitouch

I am using `UITouch` methods for moving the imageView from left-to-right and right-to-left. For this I am using below patch and its working fine

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch1 = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch1 locationInView: self.view];

    if ([touch1 view] == _ballimg)
    {
        if (location.x<=268 && location.x>=20)
        {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(location.x,  _ballimg.frame.origin.y,_ballimg.frame.size.height, _ballimg.frame.size.width);
            [_ballimg setFrame:rect];

            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    }
    if ([touch1 view] == _ballimg1)
    {
        if (location.x<=312 && location.x>=64)
        {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(location.x,  _ballimg1.frame.origin.y,_ballimg1.frame.size.height, _ballimg1.frame.size.width);
            [_ballimg1 setFrame:rect];

            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    }     
}
```

But now when two images are intersecting then I have to push the intersecting imageView from the current touched imageView either left-to-right or right-to-left. What will be the best approach?

Comment: r u moving image or image view ?

Comment: what's wrong with ur code ?

Comment: @Mr.T now i use intersection for when images are intersect then move one image by increase its x value by 10 but still this images are goan through by each other why this happen